# How do I use non-static OuterClass variable in static NestedClass?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I know static class  I use static variable but if I want I use non-static OuterClass variable in static NestedClass. Is there another way out? How can I do this? Or can I do this?

```
public class NestedClass05 {
    int num=1;

    public static class Test1{
        int num=2;

        public int Method1(int a){                
            return NestedClass05.num+a; // How I can use that
        }
    }

    public class Test2{
        int num=3;

        public int Method1(int a){
             return NestedClass05.this.num+a; // I use like this.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Please don't deface your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the static class the instance of the outer class of which you want to retrieve a variable from. Like:

```
 public class NestedClass05 {
     int num=1;

     public static class Test1{
          int num=2;

          public int Method1(NestedClass05 instance, int a){
              return instance.num + a;
          }
      }
  }
```